# How to create an overlapping bar graph?

Tags: excel, gnuplot, graphviz

For a project, I need to create a floating bar graph containing a large amount of data. To fit all of this onto a single graph, the bars have to be in line with each other. I am attempting to emulate the photo below, except with even more data.

[Ideal Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsM2F.jpg)

I talked to the creator of the graph, and he said he painstakingly drew every box. I am trying to avoid this by using other programs. However, my attempts with Excel have been failures. I looked into Graphviz and gnuplot, but have not been able to find something to guide me in creating a chart like this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what type of graph are you trying to make? Also how is your data layout in excel, is it as a table? So you just want to make a bar chart out of all your data?

Comment: Yes, my data layout is currently in Excel. I basically have around 300 chemicals with ranges of concentration for each. (Ex: Na- 6nM to 12nM, Cu- 10nM to 30nM, etc.). I am trying to display this graphically (like the attached image in the OP), but I cannot find a program to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you build it vertically rather than horizontally (and rotate afterwards), I think gnuplot can usefully do it. You have all the necessary tools to prepare the rotation, as both `tics` and `labels` can be arbitrarily rotated (`rotate by`)

So if your data is of the type:

```
 Cu 10 30
```

you could:

```
unset ytics
unset xtics
unset key
set y2tics rotate
set boxwidth 1
NLines=5
plot "f.dat" u ($0 % NLines):2:2:3:3 w candlest fs solid, "f.dat" u 0:(($2+$3)/2):1 w labels rotate
```

The bit that gnuplot won't do itself is decide on which line (x coordinate in the pre-rotation plot) to put each box. If you want to optimize the number of lines as in your example, then you have to make a first pass on your data to assign them each a line number. This can be done in gnuplot if needed, but this is not the best tool for this. For now, boxes are on `NLines` different lines in order of appearance (label `0` corresponds to line number in file, `%` is modulo operator)